USB and RS485 on same lines for ESP32-S3
For an ESP32-S3 based PCB that I am developing, I would like to be able to share 1 connector for two different communication protocols.

USB connection directly to IO19 and IO20 of the ESP32-S3-wroom1
RS485 transceiver to UART on the TXD0 and RXD0 pins of the ESP32-S3-wroom1

So, the connector will be Vbus, GND and two communication pins.
Is it possible to use the same lines for these two different communication protocols?
What will be the effect of sending USB data on the RS485 transceiver and visa-versa?
Note: the communication will not be used at the same time. It will be USB OR RS485


How will you specify which set of pins on the ESP32 go to the connector pins?

They will both go to the connector pins. So I want to be able to plug either a USB cable OR an RS485 bus (I added a schematic picture for reference)

I'd use a 6 pin connector and keep them separate.

So what are the specs you need? RS-485 is 5V differential and allows for +/-7V of ground potential difference between devices. USB pins or protection for USB would be damaged by perfectly normal RS-485 range of voltages. How would your devices know whether or not to switch/mux between USB pins and RS-485 pins, and I hope you don't use a standard USB connector so that nobody damages their PC while your device sends RS-485.

Strongly doubt it.  The transceiver's capacitance will excessively load the bus, at least preventing High Speed negotiation (the connection may downgrade to Full Speed, or fail to negotiate).  Conversely, RS-485 common mode range will be spoiled by the USB interface (has clamp diodes).  Finally, USB is a source-terminated point-to-point bus (conditionally source-load terminated, in High Speed mode), while RS-485 is a multi-drop bus which may or may not have a local termination (or a low-value DC termination at all, if customized).
Perhaps the cable would be shielded in both cases, and such interference isn't expected, nor ground-loop voltage (self-powered by the cable?); but in that case, why bother with RS-485 at all when logic-level UART will suffice?  You already have a shielded cable supporting high bitrate and normal-mode signals (USB is not a fully differential standard!), UART is trivial to run over it -- perhaps with an analog switch rated for USB2.0 to select which pair of ESP pins the bus gets routed to.
